# Passando $_POST pela URL

Tags: php, url, post

1. Tenho um formulário que é montado dinamicamente de acordo com as preferências de cada usuário e é submetido via post para a pagina que faz o processo.
2. Na página de processo eu preciso dentre outras coisas, carregar um iframe que trará informações extras, de acordo com as informações do formulário dinâmico da primeira tela.

O meu problema está justamente aí: como faço para passar as informações para o iframe trazer as informações extras?

Exemplo: Formulário

```
<form method="post" action="processa.php">

   <label>Ano</label>
   <div>
      <select id="ano" name="ano">
         <option value="0">2000</option>
         <option value="1">2001</option>
         <option value="2">2002</option>
      </select>                     
   </div>

   <label>Mes</label>
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="mes" name="mes">                     
   </div>

   <label>Dia</label>
   <div>
      <input type="text" id="dia" name="dia">                    
   </div>

</form>
```

Exemplo: Página que processa

```
<?php
   $_SESSION["pesquisa"] = $_POST; //ERRO POIS $_POST RETORNA ARRAY
   $_SESSION["pesquisa"] = implode("&",$_POST); //NAO SERVE POIS FICA 2000&03&12
?>

<script>
   parent.iframe.location.href = 'mais_infos.php?<?php echo $_SESSION["pesquisa"];?>';
</script>
```

Eu precisaria que a minha `$_SESSION["pesquisa"]` ficasse algo do tipo `ano=2000&mes=03&dia=12` para poder completar a URL, mas lembrando novamente, os campos do formulário são montados dinamicamente.

Comment: Você pode tentar usar, `serialize` (para armazenar) e `unserialize` (para recuperar).

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft com o `serialize` meu post ficou algo do tipo `a:6:{s:8:"indice_9";s:6:"DOC 01";s:9:"indice_10";s:4:"2015";s:9:"indice_11";s:2:"03";s:9:"indice_12";s:1:"1";s`. Não teria alguma outra alternativa?

Comment: E no `unserialize`, você recuperou normalmente o valor? Ou você precisa que na session fique legível?

Comment: Desculpe, não havia visto que você queria passar o valor na url do iframe, você pode tentar usar também a seguinte função: `http_build_query`. Exemplo: `http_build_query( ['parametro1' => '123', 'parametro2'=> '123'] )`. E pode testar passando o post diretamente `http_build_query($_POST)`;

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Funcionou também com `http_build_query`, único detalhe é que essa funcção troca espaços no value dos campos por +.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que entendi você necessita é de passar dados de um formulário para o iframe de forma dinâmica. Como os dados vem via POST, logo viriam no formato `$_POST['nome_campo'] = valor`. Caso você fazer um

```
$variavel = '';
foreach ($arrayPost as $campo => $valor){
    if (end($arrayPost) != $valor)
        $variavel .= $campo.'='.$valor.'&';
    else
        $variavel .= $campo.'='.$valor;
}
```

Verifique se na variável `$variavel` retorne exatamente o que você deseja.

Comment: Isso mesmo! Valeu cara, muito bom. :)